# Unable to acces JSON formatted data inside Firebase database

Tags: android, json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data inside the Firebase real-time data-base in an android app. the structure of the data I am trying to read looks like this:

```
root
class1
assignment1
student1
0: answer1
1: answer2
2: answer3
student2
0: answer1
1: answer2
2: answer3
assignment2
student1 //continues just as before
```

What I am trying to do is as follows:

```
DatabaseReference ref1 = Firebase.getInstance().getReference("class"+math_class+"/"+assignmentCode);
ref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListenter(){
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    HashMap<String,String> incoming = dataSnapshot.getValue(HashMap.class);
```

The app crashes trying to convert the dataSnapshot to a HashMap.
How can I gain access to the data stored inside the database?

It crashes with the following exception:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:*** ***Class java.util.HashMap has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead***

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String,Object> incoming = HashMap<String,Object>dataSnapshot.getValue();
```